# Separate scrollbar of different UI component within a view iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, scrollbar

I am creating an iPad app that has `single view`. the left part of the view is a `tableView` and the right part is a `webView`. When user clicks on a cell in the table, the `webView` to the right load the web page that the cell's stored URL points to. Now, everything works fine, except for the whole screen has only one `scroll bar`.

What I want is something like the **Facebook App** which you can choose to scroll the left `tableView` without scrolling the webView and the scrolling of the `webView` does not affect the `tableView`. I don't know if it is the problem of running on simulator, there seems to be only one `scrollbar` for the whole App, and if I scroll my finger on the touchpad of Mac, the whole iPad simulator screen gets scrolled, instead of the individual `UI area (tableView or webView)` where my mouse lies. Could anyone shed some light? Thanks!

Comment: I just realized, everything is fine at the beginning, no need any scrollable view at all, just one UITableView and one UIWebView under the original View provided by the template will automatically have the effect I want. In order to simulate the scrolling on a view on the simulator, you have to double fingers click down the touchpad and drag, I didn't click down orignally. Make sure when you move on your touchpad, it is being clicked down.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a problem with your view hierarchy.  You need to make sure that the web view is not a subview of the table view or vice versa.

Edit:
Based on the screenshot you provided, it seems that your web view is taking up the whole screen.  You need to resize the web view so it does not overlap the table view.

Comment: i have only one view under the controller,  both the tableView and the webView are sub view of the view, parallel relationship. Do I need to put two scroll view as the sub view of the view and the webview tableview both as the subview of those scroll view?

Comment: @user1947254 That shouldn't be necessary. UITableView is already a subclass of UIScrollView and UIWebView uses a UITableView internally. Putting scroll views inside scroll views could get messy.  You might want to post a screenshot of how your app looks as I am having trouble visualizing what you are asking as what you have described sounds like it should work.

Comment: Sorry i could not post image due to the low level of my account. Could it be the simulator not able to simulate the multiple scrollable areas on it? when I scroll, the time display at the up center of the ipad screen in the simulator is scrolled away as well, whereas the time screen is always fixed there in real iPad

Comment: @user1947254 Can you include a hyperlink? If so, upload your image to an image hosting site such as imgur and provide a link to it.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the link http://i.imgur.com/BwWDq.png that shows the hierarchy of the views.

Comment: @user1947254 I have added an edit with a more specific answer based on that screenshot.

Comment: that's not the reason, here is the screenshot of the App, the two views http://i.imgur.com/EHtZK.png does not overlap at all.